# ETC Mining - DAG File to big in Phoenix miner but Claymore works without any complains

Tags: ethereum-classic, dag

I am confused, when trying to mine ETC with Phoenix miner, as I did for a long time, it calls the error:

GPU1: Not enaugh VRAM for DAG epoch 329

GPU1 is a RX580 with 4GB, but it is dedicated.
I also have an R7 installed and as the default GPU it gets used by Windows.

If I start up Claymore, mining just works without an error.
I would like to mine with Phoenix, since I get more stable clocks on my R7.

Any suggestions why it behaves like that?
Sincerely

Comment: It already explicitly stated the problem. Your graphic card has not enough video RAM to pass DAG epoch 329.

Comment: Claymore and Phoenix use different implementations of the same algorithm so their memory needs might be different.